# Migrating from PuLP to Scipy

Tags: python, numpy, scipy, pulp

Im using PuLP to solve some minimization problems
with constraints, uper and low bounds.
It is very easy and clean.

But im needing to use only the Scipy and Numpy
modules.

I was reading:
http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/tutorial/optimize.html

> Constrained minimization of multivariate scalar functions

But im a bit lost... some good soul can post a small example like
this PuLP one in Scipy?

Thanks in advance.
MM

```
from pulp import *

'''
Minimize        1.800A + 0.433B + 0.180C
Constraint      1A + 1B + 1C = 100
Constraint      0.480A + 0.080B + 0.020C >= 24
Constraint      0.744A + 0.800B + 0.142C >= 76
Constraint                            1C <= 2
'''

...
```

Comment: @Daniel Can you kindly answer this question? https://datascience.stackexchange.com/questions/49792/adding-constraints-in-pulp-optimization-problems-in-python

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Consider the following:

```
import numpy as np
import scipy.optimize as opt

#Some variables
cost = np.array([1.800, 0.433, 0.180])
p = np.array([0.480, 0.080, 0.020])
e = np.array([0.744, 0.800, 0.142])

#Our function
fun = lambda x: np.sum(x*cost)

#Our conditions
cond = ({'type': 'eq', 'fun': lambda x: np.sum(x) - 100},
        {'type': 'ineq', 'fun': lambda x: np.sum(p*x) - 24},
        {'type': 'ineq', 'fun': lambda x: np.sum(e*x) - 76},
        {'type': 'ineq', 'fun': lambda x: -1*x[2] + 2})


bnds = ((0,100),(0,100),(0,100))
guess = [20,30,50]
opt.minimize(fun, guess, method='SLSQP', bounds=bnds, constraints = cond)
```

It should be noted that `eq` conditions should be equal to zero, while `ineq` functions will return true for any values greater then zero.

We obtain:

```
  status: 0
 success: True
    njev: 4
    nfev: 21
     fun: 97.884100000000345
       x: array([ 40.3,  57.7,   2. ])
 message: 'Optimization terminated successfully.'
     jac: array([ 1.80000019,  0.43300056,  0.18000031,  0.        ])
     nit: 4
```

Double check the equalities:

```
output = np.array([ 40.3,  57.7,   2. ])

np.sum(output) == 100
True
round(np.sum(p*output),8) >= 24
True
round(np.sum(e*output),8) >= 76
True
```

The rounding comes from double point precision errors:

```
np.sum(p*output)
23.999999999999996
```

Comment: Fantastic! I was losing my mind trying to set the conditions and different bounds to each variable. Your explanations was clear. Another question: When I use >= contraints: {'type': 'ineq', 'fun': lambda x: np.sum(p*x) - 24}, if i use <= is: {'type': 'ineq', 'fun': lambda x: 24 - np.sum(p*x)}, Right? What is the effect of: guess = [20,30,50]? For this example do you see any advantage at use of "bounded" (minimize_scalar) method?

Comment: I mean, minimize_scalar for a problem with 20 or more variables and constraints. Tyvm!

Comment: @MarthaMorrigan The inequalities that you posted look correct. The program does not automatically generate an initial guess - as everything you have shown is linear this is not a big deal, but often when minimizing nonlinear equations different starting points will lead to different local minima on the equations hypersurface. I have not used `minimize_scalar` before, but it appears to be more limited then the general `minimize` function. I suggest simply trying it for the exact problem you have.

Comment: Ok. I understood. Thanks again for the quick answer.

Comment: How do you create integer constraints in the above case? Say you want your variable values to only be integers? And say variable (C) or x[2] can only have 0 or 1 values. @Daniel